# Python random positive bigint - sql datatype

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, bigint

This question might generate be a very simple answer of, "Yep, that's fine".  I'm trying to come up with a simple way to generate a random number from between (inclusive)

`1` and `9223372036854775807`

Should be easy right?  I'm doing this and I *think* it's working correctly.

```
import random
print (random.randint(1,9223372036854775807))
```

My concern is that `9223372036854775807` is the upper bound of `BIGINT` for the SQL datatype.  Does `randint` have an upper bound like the SQL datatype?  Is there some other pythonic way I should be approaching this?

Comment: randint() works with long integers, so you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) , randint returns a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for randrange(a, b+1). There's nothing about limits.

Also, in *Python 3* the plain int type is *unbounded*.

So, ***I think*** it should be fine.